# Magento bundled item not showing all products

Tags: magento

I am trying to add bundled items in Magento but, it does not shows all products.

I am using latest version of Magento, I have 5 products of same type but just two show as bundled item.

I figured out the issue: product with custom option does not shows as bundled items, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In magento, it doesn't support to add product with custom option which is set to required **yes**. It allow you to add only simple and virtual products, either without custom option or custom option with required set to **no**.

You can all only simple and virtual products, find more at **/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml** then find tag **allowed_selection_types**, you will see allowed_selection_types is simple and virtual.

> Technically, we create a simple products and after that a bundle product. When we edit/add the bundle product, we will associate simple products to it. It works very fine, but it might have issue if a simple product has custom options. If that’s the case, and if **custom options are set as required** (which is default), the simple product will not be associative to the bundle product.

So if you want to add a **product x** to your bundle product then you have to make custom option set to required **no** in **product x**. Then you will that **product x** in list.

Comment: Although your answer was spot on, I'm still trying to find a way to enable simple products with their IS REQUIRED = YES to work in bundle/grouped products.

Comment: I'm facing same issue on magento 2.3 kinldy help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  that status of the product is 'enabled' and visibility is 'catalog, search' and that you have selected a store on the 'websites' tab of the product. 
I hope this happens because of multiple store config.

Answer (score 0):

```
app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Bundle/Option/Search/Grid.php

 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->setStore($this->getStore())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('in' => $this->getAllowedSelectionTypes()))            
            ->addStoreFilter();
            //->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
```

Do this changes and all products displayed.